# Messing with environment variables for one command

Tags: php, symfony, proc-open

I'm currently planning to use Symfony's ProcessBuilder, which allows to set some environment variable which will be passed onto a `proc_open` call.

I need for a certain command to change the `TMPDIR`, and to restore it afterwards, so I was wondering if, when the modified env (and thus modified value for the `$TMPDIR` env variable) would be restored after the call, or do I need to restore it myself ? And will this value be indeed changed if need be for a particular command (which is ghostscript in my case) ?

Thanks

Comment: Assuming you are using `putenv` to change the environment variable, it will revert to the standard setting when the request is complete. You can use a combination of `getenv` to copy the old value and `putenv` to reset it yourself for the duration of the request in case something else in your script tries to use it.

Comment: I'm refering to the `$env` argument of the `proc_open` function, but I guess `putenv`  could also do the trick then...

Comment: Sorry. I wasn't reading the whole question. The env in `proc_open` is not PHP's environment. It will last as long as you keep the I/O pointer open, but only for the command used to open the pointer.

Comment: After some tests, that's what it is, so it basically does what I need it to do. Problem solved, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

After some tests, it seems that the `$env` parameter in the `proc_open` function is really to modify the environment only for the duration of the run process. So it basically covers my question. :}